Putaway and Picking of Individual Parts placed on pallet onto stoarge racks
I have pallets loaded with 10 individual Parts, which I am transporting using a forklift to various storage rack slots. My storage rack is designed to hold multiple container types, including Pallets, cases, cartons and bins. My task involves transferring the individual parts from the pallets into their designated containers, rather than moving the entire pallet. Each forklift trip carries a pallet with 10 parts that needs to be placed in separate slots, often located in different bays and aisles.
Edit1:
Current State of model:
The model currently moves full pallets to the storage rack slots.
Requirement:
Only the parts loaded on pallets need to be transferred to the corresponding slots, ensuring that the product ID of the parts matches the product ID of the pallets already in the slots. This operation should be completed in a single trip of the transporter, moving all 10 parts to their respective slots.


How would anyone be able to help with this? Show what you want, what you tried, what you expect and what you got. Happy to help but pls make it easy for us

@Benjamin Sorry if my description was unclear/caused confusion. I have edited it now for better clarity of my problem.
